# New objects inheriting previous object attributes

Tags: python, class, object

I am trying to generate a pseudo random number every time I create a new object object from a specific Class.

```
import random
class Test (object):
    def __init__ (self,value=random.randint(0,10)):
        self.value=value
```

this works fine when instantiating the first object from the class, for example

```
test1=Test()
```

will give a random integer to the attribute. So the attribute, `test1.value` will indeed be assigned a random number.

however, any additional objects created from the class will not generate a new random number, but instead, keep the value of the first. So all my additional objects from the class, have the same identical integer value for their `.value` attribute as the first object. I would have expected the part of the code that generates the random number to run again each time a new object is created.

Feel I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 2):

This is a less obvious version of the "mutable default argument" problem.  You need to think like a compiler in this case.  The method header signature is evaluated when first encountered:

```
def __init__ (self,value=random.randint(0,10)):
```

In defining the method, Python evaluates the signature: `randint` is called only this *one* time, yielding a single "random" number that will be used for all default initializations.

To get the functionality you expect, make a default you can interpret as "argument not provided", such as:

```
def __init__ (self,value=None):
    if value is None:
        value = random.randint(0,10):
```

Comment: IMO this isn't a "a less obvious version" of the other problem, it's a different problem with the same root cause.

Comment: I agree at my level of programming (and yours, as well).  I'm allowing for OP seeing this as separate or barely related.

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint(0,10)` is evaluated immediately and so every class uses the same default argument.

```py
import random
class Test (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.value=random.randint(0,10)
```

If you want to be able to pass a value to override the random value:

```py
import random
class Test (object):
    def __init__ (self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = random.randint(0,10)
```

Comment: There's no particular reason to deviate from the convention of using `None` as the sentinel here.

Comment: @chepner Good point, I've gotten into a bad habit of using `-1`

Comment: Corrected issues

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) for more info on this

```
import random
class Test (object):
    def __init__ (self, value=None):
        if value is None:
            value = random.randint(0,10)
        self.value=value
```

Comment: If the value passed is None, the random value will get replaced with None. Last line should be in an else

Comment: with that last line, it can handle both the conditions. else isn't required,

Comment: Rereading this, you're correct.